# product is not deleting

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

hi m trying to delete the products(which are coming form db) from the admin site but it shows error page which displays 'Object not found!' any solution for it,

this is code of ProductsController:

```
  public function deleteProduct($id = null){
    Product::where(['id'=>$id])->delete();
    return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_success', 'Product has been deleted successfully');
}
```

view_products.blade.php:

```
  <a id="delProduct" rel="{{ $product->id }}" rel1="delete-product" href="javascript:" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini deleteRecord">Delete</a>
```

Comment: public function deleteProduct($id) only, not ($id = null)... you are making the passed value equal with null, that's why it can't find the product

Comment: Can we see your route definition for this method? Also, are you using Javascript to perform the delete request?

Comment: @Mozammil   Route::get('/admin/delete-product/{id}','ProductsController@deleteProduct');

Comment: @PatrikAlexits still same issue

Comment: Are you using Javascript to delete the product?

Comment: yeah initially it as working but now i have removed the js and its working

Answer (score 0):

can you try this approach, although it is different but i love using it especially with javascript or with ajax call

```
    public function deleteProduct(Request $request){
    Product::find($request->id);
    return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_success', 'Product has been deleted successfully');
}


<a id="delProduct" rel="{{ $product->id }}" rel1="delete-product" href="javascript:" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini deleteRecord">Delete</a>
```

and my jquery code will look something  like this

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$('#delProduct').click(function(){
$id=$(this).attr('rel');
...then ajax call to the server here with the id
```

});
    });

Comment: Please post the html and the JavaScript code, the problem should be from them

Comment: actually i add the sweet alert on deleting any product initially it was working but then showing error, for this reason i removed it

Comment: on the anchor tag, does the product->id of your rel return any value? try viewing it using view page source to see if there is value on the rel attribute

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Product::find($id)->delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one? You might not need to do $id = null.

```
public function deleteProduct($id){
    $product=Product::find($id);
    $product->delete();
    return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_success', 'Product has been deleted successfully');
}
```